# Generic class convert from java to C#

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Convert from JAVA to C#:

```
public interface SomeInterface
{
    public <T> void invoke(Collection<T> list);
}
class someMethod implemet SomeInterface
{
    public <T> void invoke(Collection<T> list) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (itemToCount == null) 
        {
            for ( T item : collection )
                if (item == null)
                    count++;
        }
        else
        {
            //some code
        }   
        return count;
    }
}
```

If I copy this in c# it will show error:

> Error:    The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error:    Invalid token '>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> Error:    Invalid token '<' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Actually I don't know how to use this type of code in c#.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try `public void invoke<T>(Collection<T> list)`

Comment: If you will copy it straightforward into c# source code - you wil get not only errors you've mentioned, but also couple on other errors. This is due to differences in languages syntax.

Comment: this is java code but i want in c#, if i copy same in .net, error in interface only.

Comment: ya i know of syntax and all but, problem with generic method and class

Comment: Thank you @Dennis_E, you understood me and your answer is worked for me.

Comment: Also, in C# it's `foreach (T item in collection)` instead of `for (T item : collection)`. Rule #1: C# is not Java. There are enough differences so you can't simply copy paste code from one to the other. If you want to write C#, you really need to learn C#.

Comment: Guess why this code, littered with spelling mistakes so that it doesn't compile in either C# nor Java, doesn't work (and so obviously isn't even the real code)

Comment: Sorry sir, Actual problem is I am new to C# so I am learning even, the thing is the above code I want in c# so I asked how we can write in c#. I saw the same snippet from "http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c10/s5.html" in java, but i wanted in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java and C# may share similar concepts in certain aspects but both are not the same. If you want a quick intro into C# generics, check this [C# tutorial on generics](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm)

It's best you don't just copy Java code into C#. For your code, this simple example using generics may help you:

```
public interface SomeInterface
{
    public int invoke<T>(ICollection<T> list);
}

public class SomeClass : SomeInterface
{
    public int invoke<T>(ICollection<T> list)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Collection in an interface you can't do it by this way in C#.

You need to do it like that :

```
public interface MyInterface<T,TCollection>
where TCollection : ICollection<T>
{
  TCollection MyCollection{ get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore you will have errors in your class like Andy Korneyev sayd

Hope this will help you.